# Why are videos played before inserted into DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-video

Why does executing something like the following

```
var videoBg;
videoBg = $('<video autoplay>');
videoBg.attr({
    'src': 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
    'height': 360,
    'width': 640
});
```

cause the video to be played before being inserted into the page's DOM?

Isn't the idea that the user should not be able to notice elements unless they are somewhere in the DOM?

What's the difference between an object being visible and an object being audible?

Comment: See edit for elaboration on your added question.

Comment: @Chris did some more exploring in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense to me. It's being created you're just not rendering it. A workaround would be

```
var videoBg;
videoBg = $('<video>');
videoBg.attr({
    'src': 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
    'height': 360,
    'width': 640
});

$('body').append(videoBg);

videoBg.attr('autoplay', true)
```

**EDIT** Diving into things a bit further, here's a screenshot of a Chrome timeline:

[image]

Here's the call stack:

- `jQuery.extend.buildFragment @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 5089**
- `jQuery.parseHTML @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 8810**
- `jQuery.fn.init @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 2735**
- `jQuery @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 76**
- `(anonymous function) @ test.html` **Line 28**
- `jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 3073**
- `jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 3185**
- `jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 3391**
- `completed @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 3407**

Of note:

`(anonymous function) @ test.html` **Line 28** is:

`videoBg = $('<video autoplay>');`

and more important, `jQuery.extend.buildFragment @ jquery-2.1.1.js` **Line 5089**, is part of this block:

```
// Convert html into DOM nodes
} else {
  tmp = tmp || fragment.appendChild( context.createElement("div") );

  // Deserialize a standard representation
  tag = ( rtagName.exec( elem ) || [ "", "" ] )[ 1 ].toLowerCase();
  wrap = wrapMap[ tag ] || wrapMap._default;
  tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[ 2 ];

  // Descend through wrappers to the right content
  j = wrap[ 0 ];
  while ( j-- ) {
    tmp = tmp.lastChild;
  }

  // Support: QtWebKit
  // jQuery.merge because push.apply(_, arraylike) throws
  jQuery.merge( nodes, tmp.childNodes );

  // Remember the top-level container
  tmp = fragment.firstChild;

  // Fixes #12346
  // Support: Webkit, IE
  tmp.textContent = "";
}
```

Notice the line `tmp = tmp || fragment.appendChild( context.createElement("div") );`

Elsewhere it states `var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()`

Leading us to [documentation on createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment), which states:

> DocumentFragments are DOM Nodes. They are never part of the main DOM tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children.
>
> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.

Comment: Nice! That's pretty cool that you went ahead and looked at how jQuery creates the element, although I'm afraid I think that is a bit irrelevant in this case.

Comment: The behavior would be exhibited regardless of how the `video` element is created.

Comment: I wasnt suggesting jQuery was doing anything, I was just following breadcrumbs.

Comment: (Sorry for splitting this over several comments; `return` key screwed me). You could do it with `document.createElement` and it would exhibit the same behavior, for example. The fact it's a fragment is not consequential in this particular case.

Comment: Oh, I understand. What I was trying to communicate is that the complexity/indirectness caused by the use of jQuery isn't crucial to the behavior exhibited — and like I said, it's **very cool** to follow the call stack, etc. I was simply noting that the scenario isn't occurring because of the fact this is a fragment or jQuery being clever, etc.

Comment: Well of course it isn't, lol. Don't mind me, just publically playing with/learning dev tools here.

Comment: Oh, I think it's quite helpful to illustrate some of the ways to deconstruct what's going on — thanks for doing that! I was just adding to make sure future readers don't get confused. :)

Comment: Haha I think we were both in "I'm on the internet and everyone is gonna argue with me" mode. What I found particularly interesting was the bit on the Mozilla docs stating that appending elements to the fragment does not cause any page reflow and therefore better performance. Unfortunately I think use cases might be few, and according to [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/createelement-vs-createdocumentfragment) the performance difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Like `audio`, `canvas`, and others, `<video>` elements created in JavaScript are still passively functional even if they're not in the rendered DOM.

Doing

```
videoBg = $("<video>");
```

creates the element. It exists, it is functional. It is not yet a child of something in your page's DOM, though.

It simply doesn't have a connection in the DOM tree that would make it renderable.

Don't use `autoplay` if you don't want the `video` to start automatically playing. Instead, programmatically start the playback:

```js
var videoBg;
videoBg = $("<video>");
videoBg.attr({
    src: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
    height: 360,
    width: 640
});
// When you're ready...
videoBg[0].load(); // Start loading `src`
videoBg[0].play(); // And play
```

### Elaboration (*edit*)

I noticed you added to your question:

> What's the difference between an object being visible and an object being audible?

There's not really a difference, conceptually. Your `body` element is considered by browsers to be something that needs to be visually rendered.

Your `video` element is still *there* and playing, except for the fact that it's not connected to anything that would cause the actual frames to render on your display.

In fact, if you create your `video` in JavaScript and never actually put it in the DOM tree somewhere under `body`, you could still "get" the visual data by, for example, plotting the `video` frame to a `canvas` in the visible DOM:

```
ctx.drawImage(videoElm, 0, 0);
```

---

In the case of an `audio` element, it won't render the controls, the seeking bar, etc. if you don't add it to the visible DOM.

**However**, in most cases, it'll still play to speakers (because the browsers connect the sound to the speakers regardless of the `audio` element being in the visible DOM on the display).

In many ways, having a `<video>` element that's not attached to your visible DOM is roughly equivalent to simply having it in your `body` with `display: none;` applied to it.